# Regex in python: is it possible to get the match, replacement, and final string?

Tags: python, regex

For doing a regex substitution, there are three things that you give it:

- The match pattern
- The replacement pattern
- The original string

There are three things that the regex engine finds that are of interest to me:

- The matched *string*
- The replacement *string*
- The final processed string

When using `re.sub`, the final string is what's returned. But is it possible to access the other two things, the matched string and replacement string?

Here's an example:

```
orig = "This is the original string."
matchpat = "(orig.*?l)"
replacepat = "not the \\1"

final = re.sub(matchpat, replacepat, orig)
print(final)
# This is the not the original string
```

The match string is `"original"` and the replacement string is `"not the original"`. Is there a way to get them? I'm writing a script to to search and replace in many files, and I want it to print it what it's finding and replacing, without printing out the entire line.

Comment: I've been wondering this for a while as well. Good question!

Comment: Very good question. And very well formulated. +1

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
class Replacement(object):

    def __init__(self, replacement):
        self.replacement = replacement
        self.matched = None
        self.replaced = None

    def __call__(self, match):
        self.matched = match.group(0)
        self.replaced = match.expand(self.replacement)
        return self.replaced

>>> repl = Replacement('not the \\1')
>>> re.sub('(orig.*?l)', repl, 'This is the original string.')
    'This is the not the original string.'
>>> repl.matched
    'original'
>>> repl.replaced
    'not the original'
```

---

**Edit:** as @F.J has pointed out, the above will remember only the last match/replacement. This version handles multiple occurrences:

```
class Replacement(object):

    def __init__(self, replacement):
        self.replacement = replacement
        self.occurrences = []

    def __call__(self, match):
        matched = match.group(0)
        replaced = match.expand(self.replacement)
        self.occurrences.append((matched, replaced))
        return replaced

>>> repl = Replacement('[\\1]')
>>> re.sub('\s(\d)', repl, '1 2 3')
    '1[2][3]'

>>> for matched, replaced in repl.occurrences:
   ....:     print matched, '=>', replaced
   ....:     
 2 => [2]
 3 => [3]
```

Comment: This would only store the last match and replacement, but it wouldn't be hard to turned the `matched` and `replaced` instance variables into lists to keep all of them.

Comment: +1 for passing a callable class where people normally use functions. Clever.

Comment: What about when there are multiple matches? For example, `re.sub('(orig.*?l)', repl, 'This is the original origaaaaaal string.')`. Then `repl.matched` is `"origaaaaaal"`.

Comment: I've added a version that handles multiple occurrences as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10):

I looked at the documentation and it seems like you can pass a function reference into the `re.sub`:

```
import re

def re_sub_verbose(pattern, replace, string):
  def substitute(match):
    print 'Matched:', match.group(0)
    print 'Replacing with:', match.expand(replace)

    return match.expand(replace)

  result = re.sub(pattern, substitute, string)
  print 'Final string:', result

  return result
```

And I get this output when running `re_sub_verbose("(orig.*?l)", "not the \\1", "This is the original string.")`:

```
Matched: original
Replacing with: not the original
This is the not the original string.
```

Comment: I just can't figure out how to make it pretty so that it works for other regexes, as I'm using this in my own code :P

Comment: You can also call `match.expand('not the \\1')` (http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.expand)

Comment: You mean so you don't have to hard-code the replacement string? I'd maybe write a class that stores the replacement string as an attribute, and give it a `__call__` method that actually does the printing and returns the replacement string. Plus you can use `match.expand` instead of `str.format` to handle arbitrary regexes.

Comment: Soon after I asked the question, I managed to scrape together something roughly like this, but your version is much cleaner. Thanks!